# ElasticSearch autocomplete returning 0 hits

Tags: mongodb, autocomplete, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mongo-river

I am trying to build an autocomplete feature for our database running on MongoDB. We need to provide autocomplete which lets users complete their queries by offering suggestions while they are typing in the search box.

I have a collection of `articles` from various sources, which is having the following fields :

```
{
    "title" : "Its the title of a random article",
    "cont" : {  "paragraphs" : [ .... ]  },
    and so on..
}
```

I went through a [video by Clinton Gormley](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7FLXjgB0PQI). From 37:00 through 42:00 minute, Gormley describes an autocomplete using `edgeNGram`. Also, I referred to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20896317/elasticsearch-edgengram) to recognize that both are almost the same things, just the mappings differ.

So based on these experiences, I built almost identical settings and mapping and then restored `articles` collection to ensure that it is indexed by ElasticSearch

The indexing scheme is as follows:

```
POST /title_autocomplete/title
{
    "settings": {

        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "autocomplete": {
                    "type": "edgeNGram",
                    "min_gram": 2,
                    "max_gram": 50
                }
            },

            "analyzer": {

                "title" : {
                    "type" : "standard",
                    "stopwords":[]
                },
                "autocomplete": {
                    "type" : "autocomplete",
                     "tokenizer": "standard",
                     "filter": ["lowercase", "autocomplete"]
                }
             }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "title": {
            "type": "multi_field",
            "fields" :  {
                "title" : {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "title"
                },
                "autocomplete" : {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index_analyzer": "autocomplete",
                    "search_analyzer" : "title"
                }
            }
       }
    }
}
```

But when I run the search query, I am unable to get any hits!

```
GET /title_autocomplete/title/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "match" : {
                    "title.autocomplete" : "Its the titl"
                }
            },
            "should" : {
                "match" : {
                    "title" : "Its the titl"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can anybody please explain what's wrong with the mapping query or settings? I have been reading ElasticSearch docs for over 7 days now but seem to get nowhere more than full text searches!

- ElastiSearch version : 0.90.10
- MongoDB version : v2.4.9
- using [_river](https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb/wiki)
- Ubuntu 12.04 64bit

**UPDATE**
I realised that mapping is screwed after applying previous settings:

```
GET /title_autocomplete/_mapping
{
   "title_autocomplete": {
      "title": {
         "properties": {
            "analysis": {
               "properties": {
                  "analyzer": {
                     "properties": {
                        "autocomplete": {
                           "properties": {
                              "filter": {
                                 "type": "string"
                              },
                              "tokenizer": {
                                 "type": "string"
                              },
                              "type": {
                                 "type": "string"
                              }
                           }
                        },
                        "title": {
                           "properties": {
                              "type": {
                                 "type": "string"
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  "filter": {
                     "properties": {
                        "autocomplete": {
                           "properties": {
                              "max_gram": {
                                 "type": "long"
                              },
                              "min_gram": {
                                 "type": "long"
                              },
                              "type": {
                                 "type": "string"
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            "content": { 
                  ... paras and all  ...
            }
            "title": {
               "type": "string"
            },
            "url": {
               "type": "string"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Analyzers and filters are actually mapped into the document after the settings are applied whereas original `title` field is not affected at all! Is this normal?? 
I guess this explains why the query is not matching. There is no `title.autocomplete` field or `title.title` field at all.

So how should I proceed now?

Comment: From what you've shown it looks good to me, so I think something is missing. Can you update with the full mapping (retrieved from Elasticsearch with GET /title_autocomplete/title/_mapping plus the full command to index and search your docs.  You may want to use the `explain` API to tell you why nothing is matching.

Comment: @DrTech: Here's the full sequence of steps I took to replicate the same problem: http://hastebin.com/wovihomaxi.vala

Comment: Re how you should proceed? Delete and start again :)  Get it working with curl first, then figure it out with mongo.  I recommend against using the mongo river. Just push changes into ES via your app.

Answer (score 0):

For those facing this problem, its better to delete the index and start again instead of wasting time with the [_river](https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb) just as [DrTech pointed out in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21367161/elasticsearch-autocomplete-returning-0-hits?noredirect=1#comment32294292_21367161).

This saves time but is not a solution. (Therefore not marking it as answer.)

Answer (score 0):

The key is to set up the mappings and index before you initiate the river.

We had an existing setup with a mongodb river and an index called coresearch that we wanted to add autocomplete capacity to, this is the set of commands we used to delete the existing index and river and start again.

Stack is:

- ElasticSearch 1.1.1
- MongoDB 2.4.9
- ElasticSearchMapperAttachments v2.0.0
- ElasticSearchRiverMongoDb/2.0.0
- Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS

  curl -XDELETE "localhost:9200/_river/node"
  curl -XDELETE "localhost:9200/coresearch"

  curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/coresearch" -d '
  {
      "settings": {
          "analysis": {
              "filter": {
                  "autocomplete_filter": {
                      "type":     "edge_ngram",
                      "min_gram": 1,
                      "max_gram": 20
                  }
              },
              "analyzer": {
                  "autocomplete": {
                      "type":      "custom",
                      "tokenizer": "standard",
                      "filter": [
                          "lowercase",
                          "autocomplete_filter"
                      ]
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }'

  curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/coresearch/_mapping/users" -d '{
      "users": {
          "properties": {
              "firstname": {
                  "type":     "string",
          "search_analyzer": "standard",
                  "index_analyzer": "autocomplete"
              },
              "lastname": {
                  "type":     "string",
  "search_analyzer": "standard",
                  "index_analyzer": "autocomplete"
              },
              "username": {
                  "type":     "string",
                  "search_analyzer": "standard",
  "index_analyzer": "autocomplete"
              },
              "email": {
                  "type":     "string",
  "search_analyzer": "standard",
                  "index_analyzer": "autocomplete"
              }
          }
      }
  }'

  curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/_river/node/_meta" -d '
  {
    "type": "mongodb",
      "mongodb": {
      "servers": [
        { "host": "127.0.0.1", "port": 27017 }
      ],
      "options":{
        "exclude_fields": ["time"]
      },

  ```
  "db": "users",  
  "gridfs": false,
  "options": {
    "import_all_collections": true
  }
  },
  "index": {
    "name": "coresearch",
    "type": "documents"
  }
  ```

  }'