# ElasticSearch edgeNGram and edge_ngram difference

Tags: elasticsearch

In ES i saw an `edge_ngram` tokenizer (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html) and `edgeNGram` type ([ElasticSearch edgeNGram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20896317/elasticsearch-edgengram)). Isn't the `egde_ngram` tokenizer just an alias for tokenizer of type `edgeNGram`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `edge_ngram` and `edgeNGram` were accepted until 7.6.

As of 7.6, `edgeNGram` [has been deprecated](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking-changes-7.6.html#_disallow_use_of_the_ngram_and_edgengram_tokenizer_names) in favor of `edge_ngram` which should be used as of that version.